# Why can't I include "del" in title?

Tags: support, asking-questions, word-filter

I was typing out a question asking for help with the windows `del` command. Then it said that I couldn't use "del" in the title. Why can't I use that word?

Comment: On a side note, if this is a general computing question, and not a programming question, you will want [Super User](http://superuser.com/) instead.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, the error message I see when a title has this word in it suggests it is being detected as the Spanish word "del", and suggests the poster use [Stack Overflow en español](https://es.stackoverflow.com/).

[image: title cannot contain del]

Presumably this is an effort to cut down on users posting questions in foreign languages.

Incidentally, this key's full name is "delete", which I would recommend using instead.

Comment: Hmm... That was supposed to be a warning, not a block. Fixed.

Comment: Incidentally, the question was about the Microsoft MS-DOS command called `del` :) (where I would recommend "MS-DOS" in stead of "Windows", which does *not* have typable commands).

Comment: @Shog9: [meta-tag:status-completed]?

Comment: @RadLexus Start -> type "cmd" (without quotes) press Enter -> Command Window. Type `del` to your heart's content :).

Comment: Regarding the warning, shouldn't it take more than one word into account?